# React css transition throwing invalid component error

Tags: reactjs, css-transitions

Been struggling with this one for a few hours now. I'm trying to use `react-css-transition-group` to animate elements in an array. I have:

```
render: function(){
var dataSections = this.props.sections.map(this.buildDataSection);
return (
  <div>
    <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="example" transitionEnterTimeout={500} transitionLeaveTimeout={300}>
      {dataSections}
    </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
  </div>
);
```

}

It compiles fine, but when I run it I get `Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: ReactCSSTransitionGroup.render(): A valid ReactComponent must be returned.` in my console. I have no idea why. I've tried rolling back my version of both react and react-css-transition-group to no avail. I'm at a loss for ideas at this point.

`dataSections` is a valid array of elements and renders fine when I take the animation out.

Any thoughts?

---

### Update

I've since moved on to several other things in this project, and I've realized that it isn't just this package, it's any react package that exports a component. All of them throw this same error: `A valid ReactComponent must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.`

I've updated all my packages including Browserify, and React is already a peer dependency. Not sure what to do :(

Comment: Have you tried taking the `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` on top of the parent `div` and bring this `div` inside it, such that your top-most element becomes `ReactCSSTransitionGroup`?

Comment: Also, can you share what happens inside this `buildDataSection` of yours (might as well share the whole code)?

Comment: Making it the parent doesn't do anything, I still get the same error. Interestingly, I discovered that if I use the deprecated: `var ReactCSSTransitionGroup = React.addons.CSSTransitionGroup;` instead of requiring it with `require('react-addons-css-transition-group')` it works fine...

Comment: Interesting. Glad it resolved your issue though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I've figured it out, and I'm a fool.

Before I started using NPM, I was using the `react-rails` gem, and when I ported everything over to Browserify, I never took out the old gem. Because of that, I didn't notice the several different places that I forgot to require('react') at the top of a component file, because the old gem provided `React` in the global namespace and it therefor didn't throw an error.

Long story short, I had two conflicting versions of React running at the same time. Removed the gem, fixed the missing includes, and problems went away!